# Secure OkHttp with key

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, okhttp

I have this code:

```java
JSONParser jsonParser1 = new JSONParser();
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url("url")
        .build();
Call call = client.newCall(request);

call.enqueue(new okhttp3.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
        //observe reason of failure using
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
        if(response.isSuccessful()){
    }
}
```

Currently the code uses this to call the json info from "url".

I want to change the code so it passes in a key with the url and if the key matches to the one being checked in PHP, it returns the data.

Comment: add that *key* as a parameter

Comment: How does one do that?

Comment: have you tried searching for that?

Comment: Yes. To no avail.

Comment: I don't believe that. Which query you used to search?